# Не работает метод get(BeautifulSoup) в цикле for, AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'. Хотя вне цикла все прекрасно работает

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautiful-soup

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

# План:
# 1. Получиьт html
# 2. Получить view in game
# 3. Скинуть view in game на api csgo float
# 4. Проверить если паттерн == указанному пользователем, то пт. 5, иначе продолжить скан
# 5. Поставиьт в таблицу ссылку на просмотр скина, покупку скина, флоат, паттерн, и полное название скина

# steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M 2774699123308596407 A 16375236507 D 5684297427044664177
# https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29

# class Bot:
#     def __init__(self):
#         self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/dmax/Загрузки/chromedriver/chromedriver')
#         self.navigate()
#
#     def navigate(self):
#         self.driver.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29')
#
#         button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@id="listing_3523422564412371245_actionmenu_button"')
#         button.click()


driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/dmax/Загрузки/chromedriver/chromedriver')  # загружает вебдрайвер для хрома
driver.set_window_size(425, 720)  # делает размер окна 425x720


def get_html(url):  # возвращает html страницы
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text


def get_pattern(url_inspect):  # возвращяет паттерн скина из кс го
    url = requests.get('https://api.csgofloat.com/?url=' + url_inspect)
    return url.json()['iteminfo']['paintseed']


def get_inspect_url(html, patterns, url):  # получает ссылку для осмотра оружия
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    asd = soup.find('div', class_='item_desc_game_info').get('id')
    print(asd)

    things = soup.find('div', id='searchResultsRows').find_all('div', class_='market_listing_row')
    driver.get(url)

    for thing in things:
        # name, float, pattern, buy_href, inspect_href
        listing_id = thing.find('market_listing_row')
        url_hoverable = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="' +listing_id.get('id') + '"]/div[@class="market_listing_item_name_block"]/span[@class="market_listing_item_name economy_item_hoverable"]')
        url_hoverable.click()



def main():
    patterns = [15, 251]
    url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29'
    get_inspect_url(get_html(url), patterns, url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
largeiteminfo_game_info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dmax/python apps/steamMarketParserPatterns/SteamMarketPatternFinder/main.py", line 64, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/dmax/python apps/steamMarketParserPatterns/SteamMarketPatternFinder/main.py", line 60, in main
    get_inspect_url(get_html(url), patterns, url)
  File "/home/dmax/python apps/steamMarketParserPatterns/SteamMarketPatternFinder/main.py", line 52, in get_inspect_url
    url_hoverable = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="' +listing_id.get('id') + '"]/div[@class="market_listing_item_name_block"]/span[@class="market_listing_item_name economy_item_hoverable"]')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Как видно, когда я вызываю функцию `get('id')` (BeautifulSoup) вне цикла, она работает, а внутри происходит какая-то ошибка. Хотя на видео про парсер https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zlWiw99bBUk все прекрасно работает.
Помогите пожалуйста, не знаю что уже сделать

Comment: Может быть, `listing_id = thing.find('div', class_='market_listing_row')`?

Comment: напиши свой ответ именно в ответ, это была опечатка и моя тупость, запишу как правильный ответ. Если живешь в таганроге, скажи адрес. Приеду - расцелую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Вашем коде опечатка. Строка `listing_id = thing.find('market_listing_row')` ищет **теги** `market_listing_row`. А Вам, как мне кажется по предыдущим строчкам, нужны `div`'ы с атрибутом `class="market_listing_row"`.
Правильно будет `listing_id = thing.find('div', class_='market_listing_row')`.